# Image attribute function on all image styles

Tags: 7, theming, media

I have a function in template.php:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_image(&$variables) {
   if ($variables['style_name'] == 'gallery') {
       $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'lazy';
       $variables['attributes']['data-original'][] = file_create_url($variables['path']);
       $variables['path'] = 'themes/mytheme/images/grey.png';
   }
}
```

It works good. But now, I want this function on all image styles. So, removed if block but not working and crashed my site.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_image(&$variables) {
       $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'lazy';
       $variables['attributes']['data-original'][] = file_create_url($variables['path']);
       $variables['path'] = 'themes/mytheme/images/grey.png';
}
```

How can I apply this function on all image styles?

Comment: Show the code after if removal. It should not crash your site, so probably you made simple php mistake. What error log says? `unexpected }` right ?

Comment: And what about that error log?

Comment: Get blank page. Not seen error codes.

Comment: That's why I'm asking about error.log